# Are there regular situations in wich the upvote is not accompanied by a raise of reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

In my view gaining reputation on MSE shows much resemblance with fishing. Sometimes they bite, sometimes they don't. Often I wonder things like "why?", or "why not?".

Yesterday (11-11) I had my greatest [catch](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1523831/75923) ever, comparable with a $1$ meter pike :-). And this simply because I was the first, of course.

But what I noticed was that not all upvotes where accompanied by a $10$ points raise of reputation. In numbers: $15$ of the $31$ upvotes remained unrewarded.

I can imagine that there is a reason for that. Probably some "catch quotum" I thought. But when today I received upvotes again *plus* the usual raising I started to doubt my theory of quotum.

So my question is:

> Was it according to some rule that the gaining stopped or did just something go wrong?

Comment: For more info: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32160/262767 Basically: yesterday you hit the 200 points cap on reputation gained through upvotes (plus the 30 from the two accepted answers, exempt from the cap). It's been reset today so new upvotes, on any of your questions, still count.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW this is not the first time you [reached the daily reputation limit](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=75923)..

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ah, I wasn't even aware of that. Probably because that time it was not explicitly linked with only one answer, as it is now.